# sshd_config all disabled - default setup ?- Ubuntu/Apache

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Had a look at my sshd_config while setting up public/private keys (new server) and noticed that almost everything is disabled (#)

Is that the default setup for this file ?

Just wondering because I gave sudo access to a fiverr guy yesterday

Thanks for the help

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none
# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Answer (score 0):

The *commented out* entries don't show *disabled* configuration, but by convention for documentation purposes show *default* options.

So for example, if there's the entry:

> ```
> #PermitTunnel no
> ```

That means by default on this system when there's no `PermitTunnel` option defined anywhere, `sshd` will behave as if `-o PermitTunnel=no` had been given.

> ```
> #PermitTTY yes
> ```

tells `sshd` will behave by default as if `-o PermitTTY=yes` had been given.

or even this:

> ```
> #Port 22
> #AddressFamily any
> #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
> #ListenAddress ::
> ```

means it behaves by default as if `-o Port=22 -o AddressFamily=any -o ListenAddress=0.0.0.0 -o ListenAddress=::` options had been provided.

Of course, it's possible that the commented-out configuration won't match the reality, but as they are built and packaged together, they're expected to match.

The default shipped *uncommented* entries might reflect a configuration different from default `sshd` (or possibly from upstream), or might not and would just enforce or underscore an important configuration.

This information is available in upstream openssh-portable source for  [`sshd_config`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_2/sshd_config#L8):

> ```
> # The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
> # OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
> # possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
> # default value.
> ```